# init_unit_test_suite redefinition error

Tags: c++, boost-test

I am trying to compile an example from boost::test tutorial:

```
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
using namespace boost::unit_test;

void test_case1() { /* : */ }

test_suite*
init_unit_test_suite( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  test_suite* ts1 = BOOST_TEST_SUITE( "test_suite1" );
  ts1->add( BOOST_TEST_CASE( &test_case1 ) );
  framework::master_test_suite().add( ts1 );
  return 0;
}
```

But I get the following error:

> ..\src\test.cpp: In function 'boost::unit_test::test_suite*
>   init_unit_test_suite(int,       char**)': ..\src\test.cpp:23:1: error:
>   redefinition of 'boost::unit_test::test_suite*
>   init_unit_test_suite(int, char**)'
>   C:\Boost/boost/test/unit_test_suite.hpp:223:1: error:
>   'boost::unit_test::test_suite* init_unit_test_suite(int, char**)'
>   previously defined here

How to fix this?

Comment: Interesting enough, I've just compiled your example with gcc 4.6.2 and it gave no errors at all.
I remember having similar error messages though. That time I was using #define BOOST_TEST_MAIN macro and getting rid of it was enough to get it work, but it doesn't seem to be your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have defined `BOOST_TEST_MAIN` on the compiler's command line (or in your project settings if you are using VS).

Defining `BOOST_TEST_MAIN` introduces the method, which you re-introduce later:

```
// ************************************************************************** //
// **************                BOOST_TEST_MAIN               ************** //
// ************************************************************************** //

#if defined(BOOST_TEST_MAIN)

#ifdef BOOST_TEST_ALTERNATIVE_INIT_API
bool init_unit_test()                   {
#else
::boost::unit_test::test_suite*
init_unit_test_suite( int, char* [] )   {
#endif
```

http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/test/unit_test_suite.hpp